# Not accepting ItemEventArgs or ItemClickEventArgs as parameter

Tags: c#, android, monodevelop

Im following this short tutorial: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/User_Interface/list_view

This offending line of code

```
ListView.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, ItemEventArgs args) { //...
```

Yields the following errors/warning

> Warning CS0618: 'Android.Widget.ItemEventArgs' is obsolete: 'Use
>   AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs instead' (CS0618) (HelloListView)
>
> Error CS1661: Cannot convert anonymous method to delegate type
>   'System.EventHandler'
>   because the parameter types do not match the delegate parameter types
>   (CS1661) (HelloListView)
>
> Error CS1678: Parameter 2 is declared as type
>   'Android.Widget.ItemEventArgs' but should be
>   'Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs' (CS1678)
>   (HelloListView)

My solution is verbatim from the short tutorial. If I change `ItemEventArgs args` to `ItemClickEventArgs args` as the warning/error suggests, then I receive a different error indicating that it `does not exist in the current context`.

Answer (score 3):

```
aListView.ItemClick += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args) 
  => ItemClicked(sender, args);

public void ItemClicked(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args)
{
  try
  {
    String fName = ((TextView)args.View).Text;
    // Do something with clicked item text
  }
  catch (Exception) { throw; }
}
```